# Sorting trees recursively

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, tree

I want to sort children for each root inside my object tree - how can I do this?

The tree:

```
{
 folder: { id: 1, name: 'root' },
 children: [
  {
   folder: { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: 'zzz' },
   children: []
  },
  {
   element: { id: 1, name: 'aaa' },
   children: []
  }
 ]
}
```

Sorting it would swap folder and element here, etc. The actual tree is much bigger, with much higher depth. How can I do this?

I have an algorithm finding something in this tree:

```
/**
 * searchFor {
 *   type: '',
 *   index: '',
 *   value: ''
 * }
 */
var search = function (data, searchFor) {
    if (data[searchFor.type] != undefined &&
        data[searchFor.type][searchFor.index] == searchFor.value) {
        return data;
    } else if (data.children != null) {
        var result = null;
        for (var i = 0; result == null && i < data.children.length; i++) {
            result = search(data.children[i], searchFor);
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
};
```

But I honestly have no idea how can I just sort it. How should I do this?

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
/**
 * sortBy {
 *   type: '',
 *   index: '',
 *   order: '' // asc/desc
 * }
 */
var sort = function (data, sortBy) {
    if (data.children != null) {
        // sort all children here, but how?

        var result = null;
        for (var i = 0; result == null && i < data.children.length; i++) {
            result = search(data.children[i], sortBy);
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: [`data.children.sort(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
function sortTree(tree){
    tree.children.sort(function(a,b){
        if (a.folder !== undefined && b.folder === undefined) return -1;
        if (a.folder === undefined && b.folder !== undefined) return 1;
        a = a.folder === undefined ? a.element;
        b = b.folder === undefined ? b.element;
        if (a.name == b.name) return 0;
        return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
    });
    for (i = 0; i < tree.children.length){
        sortTree(tree.children[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return 0` in case they are equal.